# Bind width of element to a percentage of another element's width

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Is there any way to link an UI element's width to another element's width percentage? if my Datagrid is 100px, I want my TextBlock to be 60% of that = 60px (the datagrid's width is dynamic).

Comment: You would need a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd probably do this is with a converter.
You can bind the width of the TextBlock to the ActualWidth of the DataGrid and then use a converter to apply the factor.

```
public class MultiplyConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public double Multiplier { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double bound = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        return bound * Multiplier;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Something like:

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth,  ElementName=MyDataGrid, Converter={ui:MultiplyConverter Multiplier=.6}}"
```

Comment: I would've given the same answer but read the comments in the answers and u'll realize why we're outta luck here :(

Comment: tnx, but i have problem ui is not recognize

Comment: It's a xmlns reference. Local is automatically added to markup if you're using a recent visual studio.

Comment: now i have another problem, it say the name MultiplyConverter does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace.wpfProject1"

Comment: What namespace have you given it then?

Comment: Also. You'll see blue squiggles under the XAML until you compile. It looks in the compiled exe ( or dll ) for the thing you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is very hard, or is it ?

```
myTextBox.Height = ((double)DataGrid.Height / 60) * 100
```

Comment: In XAML, it's not possible... however, if your textbox is a cutom/user control , you can achieve it

Answer (score 0):

In Grid you can give proportional width for columns, like:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
```

First one could be you DataGrid and second one is the TextBlock. This way TextBlock will have 60% of the DataGrid's width, and also will be responsive to size changes.

Comment: i want bind 2 control, for example if you change datagrid size, textblock size must be change

Comment: I believe it's not possible to achieve that in purely XAML. What you need is a converter. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312044/wpf-pass-the-value-of-one-control-to-a-converter-to-set-the-width-on-another-c).

Comment: @IsmailHakkiTekin , it won't actually help :( Because even then, there must be some code behind to get the percentage

Comment: @zackraiyan yes it's true. Maybe one solution might be putting those 2 controls into another grid inside a stackpanel, that way you might play with stackpanel's width and keep the ratio between DataGrid and Textblock. It's hard to say without more specific information I guess.

Comment: I don't understand why he doesn't want to go with code behind even though he,himself, is setting the width of the DataGrid from code ! ?